# Extend application by download of another application

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-billing

I got an android application which is not yet released but I want it to be extendable.

So what I want to do is:
You download application "XYZ" from the market which is for example an audio player.

The user could now either play his own audio files (file selection from the system) or he could download another application from the market "XYZ Audio Package".

I've seen something similar with the available "Home Screens". They provide homescreen apps and per download of other "apps" you can extend the possibilites.

How do you do this technically?

Comment: This should help you if you don't want to extend the functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803342/how-to-release-application-plugin-using-android-market