# How to create a plugin app for an Android application

Tags: android, plugins

I want to create a separate plugin/add-on  android  app which can be installed separately. The need is like WhatsApp wallpaper application which is a standalone app. It is opened when user clicks to change wallpaper and result reflects in WhatsApp. I have something similar need.

I have a Activity in App1 which needs to  set its background image. And I have another app App2 which have a gallery of images. When the user clicks on a Button in App1 , App2 will be opened and upon selection of an image, it will return to App1 and set its background. Though App1 is already a 100+ MB app, so the idea is to have a separate plugin app for it.

I have tried below things so far. But wanted to know if there is an easy way to achieve it or some sort of guidance on it.

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2010/06/plugins.html

http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/05/31/android-plugin-application.aspx

[How to release application plugin using Android Market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803342/how-to-release-application-plugin-using-android-market)

Some example of this kind app is [Muzei](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.muzei&hl=en) , [Textra sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra&hl=en), [WhatsApp Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp.wallpaper&hl=en)

Comment: I'd say there's nothing more easy than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803342/how-to-release-application-plugin-using-android-market. Just start your gallery for result, return a resource id and access it directly.